# Система модулей и аддонов

Tags: android, addons

Многие приложения в маркете предлагают скачать аддоны как платную версию и после установки они просто добавляют функционал, но не числятся в установленных программах и не висят в процессах. Вопрос: как реализовать вот такую систему аддонов и сам .apk, который что-то разблокировывает в приложении, но сам не устанавливается (во многих случаях еще скачивает контент для воспроизведения).

Примеры.

- [Пробная версия](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) какого-то плеера.
- [Разблокировка к нему](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock&feature=top-paid).

Еще примеры.

- [Приложение](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.media1908.lightningbug) с набором звуков.
- [Дополнения](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.media1908.lightningbug.plugins.meditationpack), которые качают звуки и картинки, а потом разблокируют их в .приложении

Нашел проверку на установленный "анлок": [Sharing code](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2011/01/sharing-code-full-lite-versions-application/). Как сделать проверку на его установку, теперь знаю. Но вот как сделать сам этот анлок, что бы при установке он не появлялся в меню и процессах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение пришло в голову само, когда читал одну англоязычную книгу. Кому интересно, 
в файле манифеста категория должна выглядеть так

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Тогда приложение не будет отображаться в меню, и вы сможете использовать его для различных проверок на установку данного приложения из других приложений.